# Comapring two text files and generating a seperate text file with matching entries

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I'm pretty new to java I/O classes and finding it hard to detect the error in the code.
I want to enter the paths of two text files that contains distinct lists of numbers so that the program will compare the the two lists line by line and generate a separate text file with common numbers in the input text files.
the input files are taken into the program but it does not proceed from there.

Thanks in advance.

public class ListMatching {

```
public static String path1,path2; //paths of the input text files
public static String line1,line2 = null; //indivdual lines extracted from the files

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Scanner path = new Scanner(System.in);
    path1 = path.nextLine();
    path2 = path.nextLine();

    fileRead();
}


public static void fileRead () throws IOException {

    FileReader file1 = new FileReader(new File(path1));
    FileReader file2 = new FileReader(new File(path2));

    BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file1);
    BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(file2);

    while ((line1 = br1.readLine())!=null){
       while((line2 = br2.readLine())!=null){

                    }
                    }
} }





 public static void writeFile() throws IOException{
    Scanner path = new Scanner(System.in);
    String outPath = path.nextLine();
    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(new File(outPath));
    BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter (fr);

    br.append(line2);



 }
```

}

Comment: You are not doing anything in your while loops

Comment: Also in you loop you are going to read one line from br2, then ALL lines from br2 - is this what you want?

Comment: @user2310289 - Yes.. I think he is comparing every line of b1 with all lines of b2. Bad in terms of efficiency though - n*n..

Comment: Yes what i planned to do is compare one line of one file with all the lines of the other file and terminate the loop when a match is found

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
    public class MyClass {
    private String path1;
    private String path2;
    private String resultFilePath;

    public void doCompare() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path1)));
        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path2)));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(resultFilePath)));

        String line1 = null;
        String line2 = null;

        while ((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null && (line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)
            if (line1.trim().equals(line2.trim()))
                writer.append(line1).append("\r\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        reader1.close();
        reader2.close();
    }
}
```